# Sending Boolean value to FireStore accroding to button state

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a simple home automation project with flutter and ESP32, On my App I have a bunch of buttons that will change the state of the variables inside the firestore if they are pressed or not. If pressed send True, if not false. I'm trying to make this happen but I can't seem to get it right.

Inside the onPressed is what I have tried, all of the code is inside a Stateful class:

```
bool pressed = false;

Random no effect code...

CustomButton(
        icon: Icons.lightbulb_outline,
        text: 'On',
        text2: 'Lâmpada 1\nSchuma',
        onPressed: () => (){
             dynamic databaseReference = Firestore.instance.collection('sensores').where('Led1','==',pressed);
        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          await transaction.update(
        documentReference, _value);
        };
         },
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 30.0),

        CustomButton(
        icon: Icons.lightbulb_outline,
        text: 'On',
        text2: 'Lâmpada 2\nSchuma',
        onPressed: () => (){
        },
```

My firestore:
[image]

Second try:

```
CustomButton(
                        icon: Icons.lightbulb_outline,
                        text: 'On',
                        text2: 'Lâmpada 1\nSchuma',
                        onPressed: () => (){
                          Firestore.instance.collection("sensores").document("2KbeT....").updateData({
                          'Led1': true,
                        });
                        },
                      ),
```

The problem, was the button formating. The code send by Uni works great.

Comment: why not use mqtt to communicate to your esp32. It is lighter and cheaper to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add firebase to your app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios

(Import Firestore)

You can simply update your data:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('YourCollection').document('YourDocument').updateData({
 'Led1': true,
});
```

To Fetch your data from the server:

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection('YourCollection')
    .document('YourDocument')
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  led1 = ds["Led1"];
  led2 = ds["Led2"];
  led3 = ds["Led3"];
});
```

I would recommend using the MQTT Protocol to communicate to your ESP32 instead of storing it in firestore. Note that firestore allows you to have 20k reads and 50k writes per day so if you have devices that need more than that it would be impractical to use firestore as a communication method.

Comment: will I have to remove this: dynamic databaseReference = Firestore.instance.collection('sensores').where('Led1','==',pressed);?

Comment: I will have a look at MQTT, is it dificultier?

Comment: The data isn't changing at all.

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF did you add firebase to your app? Also, mqtt is a bit more difficult because you have to understand how to use it. Are you making an app for android or iphone?

Comment: Yes, I have added it

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF You have to import this: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Do you have discord or something? I can just msg and help you there. The code is supposed to work and I also tried it.